# React Xstate spawn machine with machine options

Tags: reactjs, xstate, xstate-react

Is there any way to pass machine options such as "guards" and "delays" to a spawned machine either through the "spawn" function on the parent machine or the "useActor" hook on the context property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a while, I find out about the "withConfig" method on the machine.
You can use it like this.

```
assign({
            machine: () => spawn(someMachine.withConfig({
                guards: {
                  //...
                },
            })),
        })
```